# Subjects and resilience logic workflow

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactive-programming, rxjs, frp

I would like to get a better understanding of the expected behaviour of Subjects when used with the resiliency operators, namely [retry](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retry.md) and [retryWhen](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/retrywhen.md).

*The following code samples will differ slightly from their JSBin counterparts (found in example links) in that I used arrow functions and types for easier consumption, this is using version 4.0.0 - 4.0.7*

My expected resiliency behaviour can be expressed with the following [example](https://jsbin.com/vamepac/19/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .flatMap( (count:number) => { 
    return count === 4 ? Rx.Observable.throw('Break') : Rx.Observable.return(count);
  })
  .retry()
  .take(5);

 Output 
 // 0
 // 1
 // 2
 // 3 
 // 0 <-- Retry means we start again from scratch (expected)
```

Up until this point everything is consistent, that is after the error has occurred on the fourth notification the entire stream restarts from scratch (win for stateless architecture).

Now comes the scratching my head part if we add a multicast operator and in doing so add an underlying Subject (in my case a ReplaySubject with a buffer of 1), [example](https://jsbin.com/vamepac/18/edit?html,js,console,output):

```
const consumer : Rx.Observable<number> = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .flatMap( (count:number) => { 
    return count === 4 ? Rx.Observable.throw('Break') : Rx.Observable.return(count);
  })
  .shareReplay(1) /* multicast(new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)).refCount() */
  .retry()
  .take(5);

const firstSubscriber : Rx.Disposable = consumer.subscribe( (next:number) => {
   console.log('first subscriber: ' + next);
});

setTimeout(() => {
   firstSubscriber.dispose(); /* Lets start fresh in that refCount === 0 */
   const secondSubscriber : Rx.Disposable = consumer.subscribe( (next) => {
      console.log('second subscriber: ' + next);
   });
}, 5000 );

Output (before error is thrown)
// "first subscriber: 0"
// "first subscriber: 1"
// "first subscriber: 2"
// "first subscriber: 3"
Output (after error is thrown)
// "first subscriber: 3"
// "second subscriber: 3"
// "second subscriber: 3"
// "second subscriber: 3"
// "second subscriber: 3"
// "second subscriber: 3"
```

A quick look into a [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/subjects/replaysubject.js#L61-L63) identifies when an error arrises the subject is marked as inError and each future subscriber will get the last notification (Line 46) and straight after a call to onError will be made (Line 50).

So Where does this leave us? In my opinion I don't believe you can ever use a resilience operator when it follows any other operator that contains a Subject (shareReplay, publish etc...).

At this point I am thinking the only way to succeed with this design would be ensuring when an error has occurred and node has been disposed, whenever a subject has been used a new one would need to be created (and down the rabbit hole we start to go)?

[multicast](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/multicast.md) can take a factory/subjectSelector:

```
.multicast( () => new Rx.ReplaySubject(1), (source:Rx.ConnectableObservable) => source );
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/multicast.js) if you use a subjectSelector rather than just passing in the subject directly for each new subscription the subjectSelector will be invoked and a new ConnectableObservable will be created (Line 11).

At this point I am unsure if sharing (via some cache) and disposing (when an error is detected) of the Subjects will actually give multicasting to subscribers?

In getting to this point I have also written a RecoverableReplaySubject whereby I had taken out the error state when disposing, this was more for testing and would expect the RxJS team put this workflow in for a good reason.

Any guidance and experience on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`shareReplay` subjects hold different semantics when it comes to error and completion. For instance, even if the underlying observable has completed (`refCount == 0`), `shareReplay` will not be completed, so that further call to it will produce (replay) the past values. Cf. [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vejawibuco/edit?html,js,console,output)(shareReplay) vs. [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/tugonigani/edit?html,js,console,output)(share).

```
var source = Rx.Observable
      .interval(100)
      .take(5)
      .shareReplay()

var first = source.subscribe( function(next) {
  console.log('first subscriber: ' + next);
});

setTimeout(function() {
//  first.dispose();
  var second = source.subscribe( function(next) {
  console.log('second subscriber: ' + next);
});

}, 1000 );
```

Otherwise, you will find there explanations about the behaviour of `shareReplay` (with a discussion of your issue) vs. the other operators:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1110
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/453 (this is a long discussion, start from `jhusain commented on Nov 4, 2015`)

The solution proposed was precisely to use a factory function for the multicast operator. In any case, it should not be too hard to try your new design and see if it works.